# "msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined"

Tags: ansible

I have a problem to roll out my users role maybe someone can help me.

I have the following Ansible role called "users"

```yaml
    - name: Create required groups.
      become: yes
      group:
        name: "{{ item.1 }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', all_required_users|combine(required_users), 'groups', {'skip_missing': True}, wantlist=True) }}"
    
    - name: Create required users.
      become: yes
      user:
        name: "{{ item.key }}"
        state: "{{ item.value.state | default('present') }}"
        append: yes
        create_home: yes
        groups: "{{ item.value.groups | default([]) }}"
        password: "{{ item.value.password }}"
        shell: "{{ item.value.shell | default('/bin/bash') }}"
      loop: "{{ all_required_users | combine(required_users) | dict2items }}"
      when: "'state' not in item.value or item.value.state == 'present'"
    
    - name: Add ssh public key for required users.
      become: yes
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item.key }}"
        key: "{{ item.value.ssh_public_key }}"
        state: "{{ item.value.state | default('present') }}"
      loop: "{{ all_required_users | combine(required_users) | dict2items }}"
      when: "'state' not in item.value or item.value.state == 'present'"
    
    - name: Remove unwanted users.
      become: yes
      user:
        name: "{{ item.key }}"
        state: "{{ item.value.state | default('absent') }}"
        remove: true
      loop: "{{ all_required_users | combine(required_users) | dict2items }}"
      when: "'state' in item.value and item.value.state == 'absent'"
```

And the following playbook:

```yaml
    - name: install users
      hosts: 192.168.70.22
      become: true
      roles: 
        - role: users
```

When ) start to run the playbook, I get the following message:

```
fatal: [192.168.70.22]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined"}
```

What will I have to do to get the playbook work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined
```

reports just that [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) are [not defined](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=AnsibleUndefined) and therefore can not be [combined](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries). It can be reproduced by the following test

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    # all_required_users: ""
    # required_users: ""

  tasks:

  - name: Create error message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.1 }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', all_required_users | combine(required_users), 'groups', {'skip_missing': True}, wantlist=True) }}"
```

Resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Create error message] ********************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: '|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined'
```

> What will I have to do to get the playbook work?

This means, you have to provide the input for `all_required_users` and `required_users`, check the parts where they are created and referenced from.